# Mongodb clone to another cluster

Tags: mongodb, database-backups, database-restore, mongodb-atlas

The idea here is, I have mongo cluster deployed in managed cloud service **atlas**. I have enabled **Continuous Backup**.

Now what I want to do is :

1) I want to use existing backup.

2) Using this existing backup I want to create similar cluster 
(having same data form backup)

3) Automate this process so that every day my new cluster gets upto date from original cluster.

Note: The idea here for cloning cluster is, The original cluster is production data. I want to create a db which has similar data on which I can plug and play using any analytic tools and perform diffrent operations without affecting production data and load.

So far what I have found is to use **mongorestore and mongodump**.But here mongodump is putting load on production db even though my backup is enabled. I want to use same backup to clone this to another db cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an offering for this purpose in ATLAS called analytic node.[Link](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/atlas-mapped-analytics-nodes-to-power-your-bi-are-now-available).

Analytic node is read replica of your database. Plus it will not interfere with your production traffic which makes it safer.

Also, you can connect BI connectors to this node and create your analytic platform.
We used [redash](https://redash.io/).

Answer (score 1):

Deployed on Atlas, your server must have replica set.
Here are 2 solutions :

- You need only reading data : connect your tools to a secondary server (ideally dedicated with priority 0 for becoming primary)
- You need to read/write data : on the same server than above, play your mongodump command with --oplog option. By this way, you're dumping your data from a read-only server, preventing slowing performances of your main servers.

In this last case, what you need will find its solution in backup strategies, [take a look at the doc to know more.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/)

Comment: Is there any other way using backup of the current cluster? As i want to have proper separation of production data and for analytics data. and i don't want to use mongodump because i only want to use backup created.

Comment: Why using secondary member is not 'proper separation'? And what do you mean by ' i only want to use backup created' (In other words, how did you create backups without mongodump)?

Comment: Answering your 1st question: I want to have separate cluster running only for these purpose.
and answering your 2nd question: I have backup enabled on my cluster so I want to use that backup for the process. Hope I have clarify my requirement :)

Comment: ok, understanded what you want, but i'm asking why. I mean, do you need to write on it (typically a dev cluster), or just read on it (analysis cluster).

Comment: Yeh primary its for analytics but in future we are planning to plug more services to it which might want to read/write to it.

Comment: ok. And do you plan to host this new cluster on Atlas cloud service, or outside?

Comment: Atlas will work for now. In future planning to go for aws but it will be mostly next year or a year after.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180800/discussion-between-matthpen-and-dhaval-chaudhary).